# javascript function call inside php function

Tags: java, javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a form which has 2 buttons: 'Submit' and 'Save'. Upon the submission of the form two kind of separate function run, depending on the button pressed. What I want to do is to call a function to check for empty fields when submit button is pressed.

Part of my code:

```
    function valuecheck(){
    var msg="";
    if($F('entrepreneur_name')==""){ 

    msg+="You need to fill the product name field!\n";
     document.getElementById("entrepreneur_name").focus();
     }

     if($F('address')==""){ 
      msg+="You need to fill in address!\n";

    }
      if (msg) 
  {alert(msg);
  return false;
   }
  }

 <?php
 $chkbutton=$_POST['submit'];
 switch ($chkbutton)
 {

 case "Submit":
 // how to call the JavaScript function here..
 ...//rest of the code
 ?>
```

the form:

```
 <input type="submit" style="width:10%" name="submit" value="Save" >
 <input type="submit" style="width:10%" name="submit" value="Submit" >
```

how to call the javascript function inside the case "Submit":

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't call a javascript function from PHP like that, you check if the fields are empty **before** submitting the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" style="width:10%" name="submit" value="Submit"  onclick="Validate()" >
```

and

```
<script>
function Validate()
{
// your validation
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the form level prior submission:

```
<form name='myform' method='post' onSubmit="myFunction()">
```

And in your js function:

```
function myFunction()
{
  if( !...)
    return false; //don't submit the form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to call JavaScript function from php function..

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
, 'yourJSFunction();'
, '</script>';
```

Or you can do this way...

```
<?php
 // some php stuff
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    yourJSFunction();
</script>
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to sskoko's answer:

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button');
submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    valuecheck();
}, false);
```

Though I have a sneaking suspicion that you will need to use `event.preventDefault()` to keep the form from submitting, when your values are invalid.

The method may have to be called either in the anonymous function passed to `addEventListener()`, or `event` may need to be passed into `valuecheck()` and then `preventDefault()` could be called down there. Play around with it and see.